# Software for managing departmental alumni relations

Tags: industry, software, community, alumni

My department is looking for a CRM tool to manage its relationship with graduated students (either on BSc, MSc or PhD level). What we want to achieve:

- Show our candidates that you can get a well paid work after graduating Physics in Poland (they don't believe such positions exist)
- Allow our department to track careers of out students and possibly change study program to better fulfill their needs
- Gain input from former students
- Allow current and former students to view/apply for job opportunities (people from our department who start a company often look for people with similar education level)

All these use cases are more or less practiced now, but mainly using emails.

I was wondering what are established practices, particularly in Western Universities (since Polish ones tend to lag somewhat, especially when it comes to such problems). **Do your departments do any kind of alumni tracking?** If yes, what tools do you use?  If not, why not?

Comment: I don't know what the department uses, but there are [numerous commercial products you can use](http://www.google.com/search?q=alumni+management+software).

Comment: GDPR applies in Poland, right?  If you're going to track your alumni, you'll need a compliance specialist on board, and that compliance specialist may have a software preference.

Answer (score 4):

[LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/) is a fine resource for this sort of thing, especially for keeping track of alums' careers and contact data. I encourage my students to link to me for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Our [Link Alumni app](https://linkalumniapp.com) helps you reunite with your classmates from the past. It aims to create a professional private network for alumni where they can connect, communicate, share and support various business opportunities and networking events.

We have customized system in which we design according to our client requirements:

1. Create awareness about the details of the job by posting and sharing the details with your alumni network. Pitch ideas to fellow alumni for a start-up and get started.
2. Give back to the community; help your alumni network by guiding them and sharing your experience through mentoring, boss talks and other CSR activities.
3. Create events and invite alumni network by sharing details and media gallery of the event. Purchase event tickets through different online payment methods easily.
4. Helping all the students in their journey by guiding and providing a solution to their concerns and problems related to before, during and also after the graduation.

Comment: Please be aware that the link is not a free service.

Comment: Above the recent comment I try to answered all things which you ask kindly review